# Mapping Virtual Hosts by folder name in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, virtualhost

I am trying to add virtual hosts to my Apache, but I am trying to do it in a specific way of which I don't know if it is possible.

I currently have it like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName til.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/til"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/til">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where "til" is the name of the folder AND of the 'domain name'.

I want to set something up once so I don't need to look at it anymore afterwards, even when adding new folders to the htdocs folder. I am going to create a lot of different domains in a short period of time so I don't want to go to the apache settings every single time I add a virtual host. Is it possible to set something up that haves all folders in the htdocs automatically be a domain name like this? So if I put abc as a folder, it uses "abc.local" and the folder "htdocs/abc"?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at mod_vhost_alias documentation.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

Configuration could look something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *
    VirtualDocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/%0"
    <DirectoryMatch "C:/xampp/htdocs/*">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </DirectoryMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that %0 stands for full ServerName (in your case til.local). If you read the docs you'll probably figure it out how to set it up the way you want.